# Is there a way to count the number of unique value across multiple columns in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, distinct

I would like to count the number of unique values based on the `tx_id`, here is part of the raw data:

```
table : Treatment Record 
+------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
|        SN        |  tx_id    |       pa3      |       pa4        |
+------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
| I2120210007014   |   149362  | V16F2021117016 |   V15S2021145018 |
| I2120210007014   |   149362  | V15S2021144019 |   V15S2021145018 |
| I2120210007014   |   149362  | V16F2021117017 |   V15S2021145018 |
| I2120210007014   |   149362  | V16F2021117017 |   V15S2021145018 |
| I2120210007014   |   149362  | V16F2021117017 |   V15S2021145018 |
| I2120210007014   |   148716  | V15C2021116010 |   V15C20211091016|
+------------------+-----------+----------------+------------------+
```

For example, the result should look like below:

```
+------------------+-----------+----------------+-------+
|        SN        |  tx_id    |  V16F |  V15S  |  V15C |
+------------------+-----------+-------+--------+-------+
| I2120210007014   |   149362  |   2   |    2   |   0   |
| I2120210007014   |   148716  |   0   |    0   |   2   |
+------------------+-----------+----------------+-------+
```

From the raw data, you can see that there are two different `tx_id` and I use this to identify each of the group. Therefore, for insance, all the `tx_id = '149362` is in the same group.

And in the column of `pa3` and `pa4`, there are 2 different group which can be categorized by looking at the first 4 characters, like "V16F", "V15S". Moreover, I have to count the number of different wordings in the same group. For example, you can see that column `pa3` contains `V16F2021117016`, `V15S2021144019`, `V16F2021117017` while column `pa4` contains only . Therefore, there are `V15S2021145018`.

Therefore, we count 2 for the group "V16F" and 2 for group "V15S". You may notice that the counting is not based on the columns `pa3` and `pa4` but based on the last 4 characters. For example `V16F2021117016`and`V16F2021117017`, they belong to the same group,"V16F", but different words since the last 4 characters are '7016' and '7017' respectively.

However I could not find a way out at this moment and only typed some sql code in below. Hopes someone can help me.

```
SELECT tx_id, 
       sum(case when val like 'V16F%' then 1 else 0 end), 
       sum(case when val2 like 'V15S%' then 1 else 0 end) 
FROM ( select tx_id, pa3 as val, pa4 as val2 from Cool group by pa3, pa4)
GROUP BY tx_id
```

Here is the wrong output:

```
+------------------+-----------+----------------+
|        SN        |  tx_id    |  V16F |  V15S  |
+------------------+-----------+-------+--------+
| I2120210007014   |   149362  |   3   |    3   |
| I2120210007014   |   148716  |   0   |    0   |  
+------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please see [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056). It seems you've posted images instead of data.

Comment: @CheTou . . . In your sample data, there are no codes shared between the two columns.  Is that always true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do it is to use `UNION ALL` to get all `pa3`s and `pa4`s in 1 column and then aggregate:

```
SELECT SN, tx_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V16F%' THEN pa END) V16F,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V15S%' THEN pa END) V15S,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V15C%' THEN pa END) V15C
FROM (
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa3 pa FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa4 pa FROM tablename
) t  
GROUP BY SN, tx_id
```

Or, with `UNION`, which removes duplicate rows, so there is no need for `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT SN, tx_id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V16F%' THEN pa END) V16F,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V15S%' THEN pa END) V15S,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN pa LIKE 'V15C%' THEN pa END) V15C
FROM (
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa3 pa FROM tablename
  UNION 
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa4 pa FROM tablename
) t  
GROUP BY SN, tx_id
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
SELECT SN, tx_id,
       SUM(pa LIKE 'V16F%') V16F,
       SUM(pa LIKE 'V15S%') V15S,
       SUM(pa LIKE 'V15C%') V15C
FROM (
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa3 pa FROM tablename
  UNION 
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa4 pa FROM tablename
) t  
GROUP BY SN, tx_id
```

Another way, is to directly use conditional aggregation with more complicated logic that works for this sample data:

```
SELECT SN, tx_id,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa3 LIKE 'V16F%' THEN pa3 END) +
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa4 LIKE 'V16F%' THEN pa4 END) -
       SUM(pa3 = pa4) V16F,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa3 LIKE 'V15S%' THEN pa3 END) +
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa4 LIKE 'V15S%' THEN pa4 END) -
       SUM(pa3 = pa4) V15S,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa3 LIKE 'V15C%' THEN pa3 END) +
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pa4 LIKE 'V15C%' THEN pa4 END) -
       SUM(pa3 = pa4) V15C
FROM tablename
GROUP BY SN, tx_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3785e98661038a0e2a160a211f78b15).

Comment: may i ask why there is a `t` after the `FROM (
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa3 pa FROM tablename
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SN, tx_id, pa4 pa FROM tablename
) `?

Comment: @CheTou It is the alias of the subquery. In MySql all subqueries must have an alias.